# Count where is not null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

For now I use

```
Appointment.where.not(time: nil).count
```

Is it possible to do this via `Appointment.count`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve this using `.count` you'll have to load all the objects from the database as then use ruby count. (From the docs: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-count)

So the right way is what you already have. It builds the query to count all the objects where the time column is not null.

Why change that?

Comment: Is there a sql perfermance problem for `Appointment.where.not(time: nil)`? The generated sql is `select * from ...` but not `SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM ...'

Comment: No. If you're using `Appointment.where.not(time: nil).count` this will generate: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "appointments" ...`. As the `count` method is an ActiveRecord implemented method. It's not the ruby core method on the array.